# Can't find Braintree APIs

Tags: braintree

I've recently registered at Braintreepayments, and now I want to generate API, so that I can use it in my woocommerce gateway. However, I cannot find where I'd do that. 
Yes, I googled it, and I cannot find API keys under Account>My user, so what should I do?

Comment: I just Googled "braintree payments api". The first 4 results are `Braintree Developer Documentation`, `Partners API - Braintree`, `API Documentation: Where to Begin - Braintree`, and `Get Started - Braintree Developer Documentation`.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

Follow the instructions [here](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials) to find your API keys. Also, make sure you are using [this WP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-payment-gateway/) that can accept your API keys.

Alternately, if you use the [new WP plugin for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/), you can simply connect without the use of API keys.

If you have any further questions, please contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says it can take up to 2 business days for these credentials to appear